# Insertion Sort on a large amount of data

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, methods, insertion-sort

I wrote this version of Insertion Sort algorithm, which permits the user to choose if sort ascending order or if sort descending order. I tried it on 20 million of Integer but it is really slow. How can I improve it?

```js
public Sorting insertionSort(int ordinamento) throws SortingException {
    if (ordinamento != 0 && ordinamento != 1) throw new SortingException("ERRORE!");
    for(int i=1; i<(this.array).size(); i++){
      T elem=(this.array).get(i);
      int j=i-1;
      if (ordinamento == 0) { 
        while(j>=0 && (this.comparator).compare(elem, (this.array).get(j))<0){
          (this.array).set(j+1, (this.array).get(j));
          j--;
        }
      } else {
        while(j>=0 && (this.comparator).compare(elem, (this.array).get(j))>0){
          (this.array).set(j+1, (this.array).get(j));
          j--;
        }
      }
      (this.array).set(j+1, elem);
    }
    return this;
  }
```

The class structure is this:

```
public Sorting(Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
   this.array = new ArrayList<>();
   this.comparator = comparator;
```

Comment: Insertion sort will be slow on large lists because it runs in O(n^2)

Comment: But is it possible that it takes more than 1 hour?

Comment: Its *probably* slow(er) because you shift each element 1 by 1 slowly until you find the location. Thats a ton of arrays elements moving around for every insert. Instead try doing it with raw arrays and simply finding the index and inserting the element there. Use a different data structure (linked list?) might aid in this.

Comment: Depends how fast your computer is. Try a few small list sizes (say 100 - 10k), graph them and fit a quadratic curve. Then extrapolate to 2M, to give you a rough estimate.